# Animation position leftover

Tags: unity, animation

I am fairly new to unity and I have encountered this same problem previously.

I have a gun with hands and I created an animation that simulates shot movements with properties `transform.position` and `transform.rotation`. Root motion is applied and motion curves are generated for the animation.The default state animation for that object has no properties assigned to it and as much as I understand from the animation controller window, the shot animation is completed before the transition to the default state is made.

The problem is that on every 3 shots 0.001 is added to the X rotation; Y and Z positions are losing some small values.

I tried to prolong the animations exit time but the result is the same. I checked the key values and the motion curves, the first and last ones are the same. Why is this happening and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Update()`, `DeltaTime`, and/or `floats` to do your calculations, it's likely that very small discrepancies are starting to crop up. Try using `FixedUpdate`, not using `DeltaTime`, and try using `ints`, see what happens.